Understanding 'aria-reflection' in LWC: Adding Debugging Logs for Clarity
Im trying to understand the aria-reflection feature in LWC's source code. To better understand its flow, I've added some console logs to it. How can I see these logs when I use aria-reflection in my LWC code? . I have used aria-reflection in playground code but custom logs added by me are not visible

for (const prop of ARIA_PROPERTIES) {
    const attribute = prop.replace(/^aria/, 'aria-').toLowerCase(); // e.g. ariaPosInSet => aria-posinset

    if (!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, prop)) {
        Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, prop, {
            get() {
                /* eslint-disable no-console */
                console.log('Getting attribute "${attribute}" from element.');
                return this.getAttribute(attribute);
            },
            set(value) {
                console.log('Setting attribute "${attribute}" on element to "${value}".');
                // Per the spec, only null is treated as removing the attribute. However, Chromium/WebKit currently
                // differ from the spec and allow undefined as well. Here, we follow the spec, as well as
                // our historical behavior. See: https://github.com/w3c/aria/issues/1858
                if (value === null) {
                    console.log('Removing attribute "${attribute}" from element.');
                    this.removeAttribute(attribute);
                } else {
                    console.log('Setting attribute "${attribute}" on element to "${value}".');
                    this.setAttribute(attribute, value);
                }
            },
            // configurable and enumerable to allow it to be overridden – this mimics Safari's/Chrome's behavior
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
        });
    }
}

enter code here


This appears to be a polyfill implementation of the new Accessible Rich Internet Application (ARIA) 1.2 specification, which will be native in browsers. Its purpose is to make the ARIA properties act like native element properties.
In older browsers, AIRA attributes had to be set with setAttribute, and read from getAttribute:
let isPressed = element.getAttribute('aria-pressed');
element.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'true');

Can now be written as:
let isPressed = element.ariaPressed;
element.ariaPressed = 'true';

